# Should the exposure count rewind with the film rewind knob for Nikon film bodies?

Tags: nikon, film

Simple question: should the exposure count rewind with the film rewind knob for Nikon film bodies? I've noticed that as I'm rewinding the film, the exposure count stays at whatever it was at until I open the back. Is this normal behavior?

Comment: Simple answer: yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while, but as I remember it the actual frame count does not decide when the the film should be rewound.  When the film comes to a stop the film is rewound.  And yes, the frame count is reset first when the back is opened.

Answer (score 0):

It is **opening** up the back that resets the film counter, not the rewinding of the film.

Comment: IIRC, the F-801 counts back when rewinding. Which is not the case of the older bodies, those with a rewind knob.